# Magento: how to translate action tag content?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have default page.xml.

I have added

```
<block type="core/text" name="for_everyone">
   <action method="setText" translate="text"><text>Some text!</text></action>
</block>
```

to

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

and I got this one:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
    <block type="core/text" name="for_everyone">
        <action method="setText" translate="text"><title>Some text!</title></action>
    </block> 
</block>
```

Then I added two files for my theme:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv

"Some text!","Some text!"
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv

"Some text!","un text!"
```

But every time I run any language I see "Some text!". At the same time selected lang for website is used correct. For example the string from catalog.xml translates perfect:

```
<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
      <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
      <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
</block>
```

I also tried to use smth like that and other tags:

```
<action method="setText" translate="title"><text>Some text!</title></action>
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `translate` attribute should contain a space-delimited list of tag names to translate. For example, if the argument one is passing to `Mage_Core_Block_Text::setText()` is encapsulated in ` node, you should have the following:

```
<action method="setText" translate="foo"><foo>Some text!</foo></action>
```

Unless one is trying to pass in an array structure via layout XML, argument node names do not matter.

Also worth noting is that if one sets the `module` attribute, that string will be passed to the helper class factory method (`Mage::helper()` - see timeline below). For instances where incorrect translation is being seen, verify that there are no overriding entries in the `core_translate` database table, which would only be entered if inline translation has been used.

Call sequence:

- `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::loadLayout()`

  - `::generateLayoutBlocks()`

    - `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateBlocks()`

      - `::_generateBlocks()`

        - `::_generateAction()`

          - `::_translateLayoutNode()`

It is `_translateLayoutNode()` which processes the translate attributes of the `<action />` directives:

```
if (isset($node['module'])) {
    $args[$arg] = Mage::helper((string)$node['module'])->__($args[$arg]);
}
else {
    $args[$arg] = Mage::helper('core')->__($args[$arg]);
}
```

Comment: Thx! Could you give some example or link for class factory method please. I mean how the module="smth" works.

Comment: for nested blocks use dot like `translate="foo.bar"` will translate `<foo><bar>Some text!</bar></foo>`

Answer (score 2):

Check the name of your `locale` folder (trailing e)

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/local/en_US/translate.csv
app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

Comment: Sorry, I got it when I've typed it here. Fixed it.